# Is casein suitable for long hours of fasting?

Tags: diet, nutrition

Say I’m doing an intermittent fast of 6-8 hours. What should I have just before the fast? The assumption is that casein will take a while to digest but will it make the fasting any easier? If so, how? And how much should be taken with the above conditions in mind?

The fasting actually represents the period of time in which I’m outside clubbing. So dancing, moving around, jumping up and down, and all that. So light exercise. Technically my Apple Watch tells me I burn upwards of 600 calories. I typically leave home at 10 and return at say 4 in the morning. The worst thing happens. I end up binging just to satisfy my hunger before going to bed.

What will casein protein do for me assuming I take it before going out and before bed?

Comment: One question I have is; why are you taking casein protein in the first place? Do you need it?

Comment: Apparently it digests slower. Will this make me less hungry or fill my stomach up? I’m trying to use it as a hunger suppressant.

Answer (score -2):

Whey protein is still the best supplement to have post-workout. Similarly, if you're intermittent fasting, casein protein can help stave off hunger pangs before your first meal, as its been found to promote `satiety — the feeling of being full`.

Comment: The first part of your answer was plagiarized from https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/casein-protein-is-highly-underrated#section8. I have removed it. In the future, continued plagiarism can lead to suspension of your account.